# ejecutar archivo python desde aplicación php

Tags: php, python

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que registra usuarios (algo muy habitual). Entre otras cosas, los usuarios deben adjuntar la foto de su dni. Todo esto lo hemos desarrollado con PHP.

Para verificar que este DNI es correcto, hemos utilizado las librerías de python pytesseract y opencv con los que leemos mediante OCR los datos de la imagen.

De forma individual, los códigos funcionan bien, pero necesito que el archivo de python se ejecute al cargar la imagen (es decir, al hacer submit). Esto es lo que tengo:

```
<?php if (isset($_FILES['imagen'])){?>
<img src="<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name'] ?>" style="max-width:400px"> //esta línea carga una vista previa de la imagen
 <?php exec('C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe \TextDetection\textDetection.py') ?> //esta es la que quiero que ejecute el script
<?php }?>
```

No sé si además sería posible hacer un log para ver lo que ocurre en el proceso y así poder depurarlo.

Tampoco estoy seguro de que el procedimiento sea el más óptimo, por lo que asumo que pueda estar completamente equivocado desde ya.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: se supone que ese script ejecutado con el exec tiene que cojer la imagen? si es asi no estas enviando como parametro la imagen en el exec... Por otra parte, presupones que la app siempre va a estar en un windows?  La ruta esa no te va a funcionar si subes tu app en un linux...

Comment: verifica si tienes safe_mode activado. En la documentación de php indica: Cuando safe mode está habilitado, sólo se pueden ejecutar los archivos que se encuentren dentro de safe_mode_exec_dir.

Comment: sí, tiene que pasar la imagen. 
De momento sí, solo va a correr en Windows.

Comment: ¿Pretendes ejecutar el script en el equipo cliente?

Comment: no, en el servidor.

Comment: safe mode no está activado

Comment: Necesitas capturar la salida del comando, revisa el [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php) para ver los ejemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir un script desde PHP puedes usar la función `shell_exec`

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> shell_exec — Ejecutar un comando mediante el intérprete de comandos y
> devolver la salida completa como una cadena
>
> Descripción
>
> `shell_exec ( string $cmd ) : string`

Para ello dentro de la función la ruta completa en donde se encuentra el instalador de python y la ruta junto con el nombre del archivo escrito en python, por ejemplo:

```
<?php

echo shell_exec('C:\ruta_a_python\Python\Python37-32\python.exe hello.py')
//Imprimirá en pantalla "Hello World"
```

El resultado lo puedes almacenar en una variable y luego puedes manipularla como gustes.